# What does projectile protection mean?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I am enchanting my boots [minecraft Xbox 360] but I always get projectile protection. But I don't know what it means?

Comment: In the future, try to specify the subject in the tags, I've submitted an edit to add the correct tag, cheers =)

Comment: Its also worth noting that if your not asking a question unique to the context of the console, you should not use console tags.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the minecraft wiki, as there's not really anything more to add than a basic definition.

[Projectile protection](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Projectile_Protection):

> Includes damage from arrows, ghast/blaze fire charges, etc.

As you might expect, "Projectile protection" does in fact, protect you from projectiles...

It's worth noting that this will **NOT** protect you if a Ghast projectile explodes near you (That would require "Blast Protection")

In case this is a problem of translation, here's Google's definition of "Projectile":

> An object propelled through the air, especially one thrown as a weapon.